# Android - How to continuously listen for a static variable change from a Fragment class?

Tags: java, android, static, android-fragments

Say for example, I have a static class like this

```
public static class MyClass {
    private static String aString;
    public static String setAString(String aString) {
        this.aString = aString;
    }
    public static String getAString() {
        return aString;
    }
｝
```

How could a Fragment knows if there is a change of the value of "MyClass.aString"?

(It's of course ok to use a forever loop but I think it should be avoided...)

Many, many thanks for a help!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Answer (score 2):

You can make your class 'Observable' and notify the 'Observers' as the value changes.
Take a look at [this.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/observable_notifyobservers_object.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You put the static variable in `preference` and use `onPreferenceChangeListener` to get the event.

Comment: what is the preference ?

Comment: Preference is like a database which the application can access. But it is stored as a key value pair. Its much simpler to create a preference than an actual database.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference

you can actually create a listener to listen whenever the actually changed